# I have a function that calculates and returns the balance of a customer, but it returns the following error to me

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-error-1415

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION  CalSoldeClient (vID_Cli int) RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE Solde Double;

select sum(Mt_Reg) SumMtReg from t_regcli where id_Cli = vID_Cli;

select sum(Mt_Credit) SumMtCredit from t_credit where id_Cli = vID_Cli;

select SoldeInit from t_clients where id = vID_Cli;

set Solde = SumMtReg - (SumMtCredit +  SoldeInit);


RETURN Solde;
END
```

ERROR 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Comment: The error message is clear (and generated by those selects), You possibly need select ..into

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the result from select in a var you should use SELECT INTO a declare the proper vars

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION  CalSoldeClient (vID_Cli int) RETURNS double
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
  DECLARE IntoSoldeInit Double;
  DECLARE SumMtReg Double;
  DECLARE SumMtCredit Double;
  DECLARE Solde Double;

  select sum(Mt_Reg) INTO SumMtReg from t_regcli where id_Cli = vID_Cli;

  select sum(Mt_Credit) INTO SumMtCredit from t_credit where id_Cli = vID_Cli;

  select SoldeInit INTO  IntoSoldeInit from t_clients where id = vID_Cli;

  set Solde = SumMtReg - (SumMtCredit +  IntoSoldeInit);


  RETURN Solde;
  END
```